# A RSA crypto CTF chanllenge with known private key ,cipher text and modules factor n

Tags: rsa, attack

Here is a CTF chanllege about RSA(The competition has ended for serval hours),and here is the critical encryption code:

```
.........
def encrypt(msg):
    p, q, r, t = getPrime(256), getPrime(256), getPrime(256), getPrime(256)
    n = p ** 2 * q * r * t
    phi = (p - 1) * (q - 1) * (r - 1) * (t - 1)
    privkey = inverse(n, phi)
    c = long_to_bytes(pow(bytes_to_long(msg), n, n))
    return [c, n, privkey]
........
```

What i knew is the list:[c, n, privkey].

I need to recover p and q so that i can complete this Challenge.
Here are some methods i've tried:

Try to brute k in :
$$privatekey\cdot n=k\cdot phi+1$$but it not working;

And using yafu to factor n also failed.

I thought this code maybe about to Schmidt-Samoa_cryptosystem:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmidt-Samoa_cryptosystem,but the way to generate private key are not the same.

And we can see the phi function seems not as normal as calculate $\phi(n)$ when $n=p\cdot q$ or $n=p_{1}^{k_1}\cdot p_{2}^{k_2}.....p_{n}^{k_n}$.

I thought the most hardest part of this problem is how to factor modules with know (c,n,d).But i tried what i knew,all not working.

I want to know if there are some ways i can use to factor modules like this situation,i will be more than delighted if someone can help me with it.

Comment: @kelalaka: actually $c^{privkey} \bmod n$ is (in general) not the original message; that's because $n$ isn't square-free, and the $phi$ computation assumes it is.  In terms of using $privkey$ to factor $n$, that's only a minor complication; the standard technique can be tweaked so that it still works...

Comment: @kelalaka: we have $e$, it's $n$ (as in Clifford Cocks's [_A Note on 'Non-secret Encryption'_](http://fgrieu.free.fr/histnse/Cliff%20Cocks%20paper%2019731120.pdf))

Comment: @fgrieu  how badly I've read this code! Okey, that is solvable than What a nice typewrite usage there.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to recover p and q so that i can complete this Challenge.

There is a slight complication; we can recover $p$ and know that $q$ is one of three values, but we don't know which one it is.

In any case, we know a value $privatekey \cdot n - 1 = k \cdot (p-1) \cdot (q-1) \cdot (r-1) \cdot (t-1)$.

What this means is that (for $g \text{ r.p. with } p, q, r, t$):

$$g^{privatekey \cdot n - 1} - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod p$$
$$g^{privatekey \cdot n - 1} - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod q$$
$$g^{privatekey \cdot n - 1} - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod r$$
$$g^{privatekey \cdot n - 1} - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod t$$

but (most likely)

$$g^{privatekey \cdot n - 1} - 1 \not\equiv 0 \pmod {p^2}$$

What this means is that if we compute $\gcd(g^{privatekey \cdot n - 1} - 1, n)$, that's (unless we are quite unlucky or were silly enough to pick $g=1$) the value $p * q * r * t$.  Divide that number into $n$, and that gives us $p$.

Now that we have that, now comes the task of recovering $q, r, t$.  We can compute $n' = n / p^2$ (just to make our lives a bit easier).  And, we can compute $z = (privatekey\cdot n - 1) / 2^\lambda$ odd (that is, $\lambda$ is the integer that makes $z$ an odd integer), and then we can pick random $g$ values, and compute:

$$f(g, \alpha) = g^{z \cdot 2^\alpha} \bmod n'$$

for various $\alpha$ between 0 and $\lambda$.  If $f(g, x) \ne 1, n'-1$ but $f(g, x+1) = 1$, then $\gcd(f(g, x)-1, n')$ is a nontrivial factor of $n'$, that is, either $r, s, t, rs, rt$ or $st$.  Do this a couple of times with various $g$ values and this will quickly recover all the $r, s, t$ values (but won't tell you which is which).

If you know your number theory, it should be straight-forward to see how this works.

Comment: Did you mean $\gcd(f(g, x-1)-1, n')$ insted of $\gcd(f(g, x)-1, n')$

Comment: @kelalaka: no, I got it right this time.  Remember, $f(g, x+1) = 1$, and we want the one before that, and that's $f(g, x)$.  What we have in that case is that $f(g, x) \equiv 1$ for some of $\bmod q, r, t$ but not all (if it were all, then $f(g, x)=1$, if it were none, then $f(g, x) = n'-1)$; hence $\gcd( f(g, x) - 1, n')$ reveals factors...

Comment: That is so true. The only missing part from the question and answer for people don't see it is _where the first we know..._ That is from the calculation of the inverse of the $e$ with the ExtGCD.